# How to ignore sc_mode=edit for anonymous user at sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have found interesting case,

if anonymous user try to open sitecore url with included parameter sc_mode=edit, sitecore try to render this page (some exception happens in my code), 
I expected that sitecore should ignore this parameter for anonymous user. 
In case sc_mode=preview I see result page for a moment and after redirect to login page happens.

How to ignore this parameter for anonymous, What would be the best option for handle this case ?

I wonder about some pipeline but not sure.

Comment: When you add ?sc_mode=edit and you are an anonymous user default behaviour is to redirect you to login page.Please try in incognito mode to add ?sc_mode=edit to your url and see what is happening.I guess you have some custom code regarding edit process.

Comment: I do it in incognito mode. This case from there

Comment: I'm guessing that you're worried about your Content Delivery servers and users trying to access pages with `sc_mode=edit` parameter? I don't know what's the reason of your problem, but you can safely remove the `sc_mode=edit` parameter from any url on your CD servers using either URL rewrite module, some Load Balancer rule or maybe `httpRequestBegin` pipeline processor if other options are not available for you.

Comment: Setting of edit mode is performed in Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.Kernel processor. But it is highly not recommended to change it, as it is one of core providers.

Comment: @MarekMusielak on CD server this is a problem as well you are right. For authors it is  a problem as well, sometimes they  try to open page directly with  sc_mode parameter as anonymous users. I believe that pipeline should help. But for me it look like a hack solution.

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde check if Sitecore behaves in the same way on clear Sitecore instance which uses same Sitecore version (loads the page partially and then redirects to the login screen). If yes, contact with Sitecore Support, if no, it means you broke it in your application and without your code no one will be able to help you.